# Javascript API within a Widget

Tags: desire2learn

Im using the Valence API to grab Department data to cross reference again RSS feeds. The widget will display data pertaining to its own department. The app is partially completed and works outside of the Widget

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Web' of undefined D2L.LP.Web.Desktop.default.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Web' of undefined D2L.PlatformTools.Homepage.default.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Web' of undefined 30570:1012
```

I imagine somewhere down the call stack its interfering with the LE. Is there a better solution working with Valence in Widgets?

Answer (score 0):

When you mention that you're building this app inside of a widget, are you using a Custom Widget, or a Remote Plugin Widget? A Remote Plugin is designed to ease the integration between LTI, Valence and the D2L interface. There are several blog posts about using Remote Plugins, such as the BookList widget post: http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/10/01/revisiting-the-booklist-sample-with-restsharp/

As for diagnosing the issue you're facing, have you tried using a utility like Fiddler to pinpoint exactly which API call is failing? There's a blog post about that utility here: http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/03/26/troubleshooting-your-web-applications-using-a-network-trace/.

Comment: Thank you for this. It got me back on track. Do you know how I could possibly get the return strings or at best the current course offering code or id? I was going to use this information to cross reference its department with. If this can be done without return strings and more to Valence that is also welcome.

Comment: There's an API Recipe on the Valence Developer Blog all about course search, and how to iterate thru to get course info. That might be a good starting place to see how to go about extracting that data using Valence: http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/07/04/api-cookbook-course-search/.